Expo Image Picker URI to URL
I'm using expo image picker, after the function is done i get an URI tha looks something like this:
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FAtt38-9e0c0770-b06a-4737-b46b-079892e4cc04/ImagePicker/b1b2d900-7dd5-43f1-9f76-14b336215f6b.jpeg
how do i convert this so that i can fetch this to my backend storage ( currently using supabase ) and turn it into usable URL? or is there a way to directly convert it within the code?
tryed to convert it with setImageObjectURL( URL.createObjectURL(imageURI.file) )
directly uploading to supabase and loading URL,  but apparently im doing something wrong
